# Angular ControlValueAccessor writeValue() not called when model mutates

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am developing an Angular custom form component which should work on parts of an entire object model, while other standard form components work on other parts of the same model.

To do this, I have implemented `ControlValueAccessor` using [this Thoughtram blogpost](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html) as a model.

For some reason, writeValue() for this component is not being called when another component in the same form mutates the model although for some reason, standard controls inside the component are updating.

[This stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7jwkb) based on the Thoughtram post, illustrates the problem:

CounterInput1Component receives `outerModel.integer` as its ngModel, and operates on that.

CounterInput2Component receives the entire `outerModel`, then operates on the `integer` property.

When the integer is incremented, either via the standard input control or `Counter2`, `writeValue()` is called for `Counter1`.

However for `Counter2`, `writeValue()` is called (twice) on instantiation but never thereafter, whether incrementing from `Counter1` or from the standard input control.

Why isn't `writeValue()` being called for Counter2? And how is it that in spite of this, its internal components *are* being told to update?

Answer (score 1):

It's not problem of your custom control form, remember that an object not change when you change a propertie of the object. You need change all the object

e.g. your input like

```
<input name="standardInput" 
     [ngModel]="outerModel.integer" 
     (ngModelChange)="outerModel={integer:$value}" />
```

Or a button

```
<button (click)="outerModel={integer:20}">click</button>
```

Aclaration:
writeValue only happens when change the "object", and this happens in any control. see an example using a formControl in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agmhxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

It's a simple formControl,

```
  form=new FormControl(this.data)
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      this.counter++
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
  click()
  {
   this.data.integer++
  }
    change()
  {
   this.data.integer++
   this.form.setValue(this.data);
  }

<pre>
{{form.value |json}}
Counter changes:{{counter}}
</pre>
<button (click)="click()">click</button>
<button (click)="change()">change</button>
```

We can not take account because the object is the same outside and inside the component, so the propertie change and you can see the real value, but repeat, there're not change

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My understanding was that Angular change detection would still work as long as the object is not marked mutable. So in this case - where I want controls in the same form to work on both parts of the model and the whole model - how do I make things work? I know that instead of making a two-way binding to each of the components, I could use a one way binding and then an event handler to replace the entire model, but this seems very messy indeed.

Comment: writeValue only happens when change the "object", and this happens in any control. see an example using a formControl in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agmhxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. We can not take account because the object is the same outside and inside the component, so the propertie change and you can see the real value, but repeat, there're not change

Comment: Thanks for your help and I do understand the point you are making. However I'm sure there must be a way to work around this without having to write event handlers forcing every other control to replace the model object. This